# The notice struck me pleasantly

Tags: adverbs, adverb-position

Is it grammatically correct to write this sentence with the adverb at the end?

I assume it would be more acceptable to write this sentence as "The notice pleasantly struck me," but I like the less-common phrasing more, assuming it's correct. If it's incorrect, why is that so?

Comment: *You waited for me patiently*. That's a standard formation.

Comment: Could you give more context, please? Ending a sentence with an adverb is perfectly acceptable and is, probably, more common than placing the adverb before the verb but "The notice struck me pleasantly" sounds really odd to me.

Comment: The notice/greeting card/message struck me pleasantly, cheerfully, happily, dreadfully? Something wrong here.